# I have tried to add subtitles to mp4 video but no luck

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, subtitle

The command used is

```
ffmpeg -i Overdrive.mp4 -i Overdrive.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy Overdrive-sub.mp4
```

The process ended successfully but no subtitles were burnt. I need help.

Comment: That will embed the subtitles into the containerfile, but not encode the subs as part of the video stream. What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to add hard subtitles to your video, you should be able to just do this:

```
ffmpeg -i Overdrive.mp4 -vf subtitles=Overdrive.srt Overdrive_hardsubs.mp4
```